# Can the Lie derivative of a Riemannian metric be expressed in terms of the Lie derivative of a Lorentzian metric?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

On a Lorentzian manifold with metric (M,g) with a vanishing Euler-Poincare characteristic, there exists a line element vector X which has a collinear vector u (Manifold Theory: An introduction for mathematical physicists p183). Let M be endowed with a Riemannian metric $g^{+}$. A Lorentzian metric can then be constructed as $ g_{\alpha\beta}=g^{+}_{\alpha\beta}-2u_{\alpha}u_{\beta}$. X is timelike and globally hyperbolic so we don't have any closed causal curves.

Consider an open subset that contains $g^{+}$ on M with the Lie derivative along an arbitrary vector $\xi$,  $L_{\xi}g^{+}_{\alpha\beta} $. The question is then, can one express this Lie derivative along $\xi$ as $ L_{X}(g_{\alpha\beta}+2u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})$? If not, please provide the details to fix this expression.

Comment: I don't understand the question. We fix a Riemannian metric $g^+$, and then ask if, for any vector field $\xi$, there is a nonzero vector field $X$ so that $L_{\xi}g^+=L_X g^+$? I am not seeing any Lorentzian geometry in that question, but I am not sure I have the right question.

Comment: Ben, we are on a Lorentzian manifold with metric g. It is constructed as shown. So yes, I would like to be able to use $L_X (g+2uu)$ where u exists only on that manifold.

Comment: @Kolten Welcome to MO. Please rewrite the question using more standard terminolgoy.  Your definition of $X$ and $u$ doesn't make any sense to me. Is $X$ related to $g$? Is the $g_{\alpha\beta}$ the Lorentzian metric you started with? But then $g^+$ can't be arbitrary as your phrasing suggests. Are you really asking if $L_\xi g^+$ is expressible for any $\xi$ with $L_X$ or is it a typo?

Comment: If I understood  the problem correctly, then $L_{X-\xi}g^+=0$, a nonzero Killing field for the Riemannian metric. Generic Riemannian metrics do not have these. Therefore the answer is no, if I have the right question.

Comment: Vit, X exists on a Lorentzian manifold. That means there is a unit vector collinear with X from which $g=g+-2uu$ So u is related to X. There is no typo, but from the other comments it appears that even though $\xi$ is arbitrary, one cannot replace it with X. But that bothers me why that cannot be so. Ben has a comment in that regard.

Comment: Ben, do you have any suggestion on how to invoke the line element vector X in the Lie derivative, instead of the vector $\xi$ associated with the Riemannian metric? I assume you agree that $L_{\xi}g^{+}=L_{\xi}(g+2uu)$.

Comment: Why is $\xi$ associated with the Riemannina metric? It is just a vector. Also, what is the definition of "line element vector"? I have not see that term before.

Comment: Willie, a line element field (X,-X) at a point p on M is a regular timelike vector field unique up to a sign. u is a unit vector collinear with one of the pair in the line element field. If $\xi$ is a vector in the Riemannian open subset of M, it might even vanish on part of M, whereas X does not. But I assume if we work with the non-vanishing part of $\xi$ locally in that subset, there should be no problem with using $ L_{\xi}g^{+}=L_{\xi}(g+2uu)$.

Comment: You question has a typo maybe? In the OP you want $L_\xi g^+ = L_X (\ldots)$.

Comment: Willie, that is what I would like to say, but Ben points out that I can't. Do you have any insight how to associate the Riemannian vector with the Lorentzian one, or am I wasting my time with that and should use the non-zero part of $\xi$?

Comment: If $\xi$ is just some random vector field, there is absolutely nothing you can say. You are wasting your time even if you try to use the non-zero part of $\xi$.

Comment: What if I just used the line element vector X on M instead of any particular Riemannian vector? In other words, $ L_{X}g^{+}=L_{X}(g+2uu)$
should hold in the Riemannian open subset on M. Although I have a calculation that involves 
$L_{\xi} g^{+}$ and holds only in that set. But that set belongs to M where X exists. That, again, is my problem.